# Give results for selected rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the results for every row that I selected in the `$sql = "";`
But I didn't managed to succeed. Tryed different codes but none of them worked. This is my code:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9, player10, player11, player12, player13, player14, player15, player16, player17, player18, player19, player20, player21, player22, player23, player24 FROM `savedpacks` WHERE `packid`=" . $_GET['id'] . "";

    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result2)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id`=" . $row2['player1'] . "";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);   
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result);    

    if ($row['Revision'] != 0) {`
```

I'm trying to get the results of every selected row, so player1, player2, etc.. But as you can see I managed to only get the row of player1. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: u r getting only player one data because of ` WHERE `id`=" . $row2['player1']`

Comment: @devpro That's my question, how to get the data from all rows

Comment: use a for loop within the while loop and use the inner query within that loop like while(...) { for($i=1;$i<=24;$i++) { $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id`=" . $row2['player1'] . "";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);   
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result);    

    if ($row['Revision'] != 0) {`}

Comment: what @sujivasagam wrote... inside loop do `.$row2[$p]."";`, where `$p = "player".$i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for loop inside while loop like this

```
$sql2 = "SELECT player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, player7, player8, player9, player10, player11, player12, player13, player14, player15, player16, player17, player18, player19, player20, player21, player22, player23, player24 FROM `savedpacks` WHERE `packid`=" . $_GET['id'] . "";

    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result2)) {
    for($i=1;$i<=24;$i++)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id`=" . $row2['player'.$i] . "";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);   
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result);    

        if ($row['Revision'] != 0) {`...}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:

```
$sql2 = "You Query";

$players = array();
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $players[] = $row2;
}

foreach ($players as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players_db` WHERE `id`=" . $value . "";    
}
```

Store values into an array and than use foreach loop and get `$value` for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join query to this

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players_db as P join savedpacks as S on (S.id = P.player1 || S.id = P.player2 || S.id = P.player3 || S.id = P.player4 || S.id = P.player5 || S.id = P.player6 || S.id = P.player7 || S.id = P.player8 || S.id = P.player9 || S.id = P.player10 || S.id = P.player11 || S.id = P.player12 || S.id = P.player13 || S.id = P.player14 || S.id = P.player15 || S.id = P.player16 || S.id = P.player17 || S.id = P.player18 || S.id = P.player19 || S.id = P.player20 || S.id = P.player21 || S.id = P.player22 || S.id = P.player23 || S.id = P.player24) where S.packid=" . $_GET['id'] . "";
```

You can get the result in single query iteslf instead of using 2 queries